# Sum up the index value in multiple array with pyspark

Tags: python, mapreduce, pyspark

I have 50 array with float values (`50*7`). How am I suppose to sum up the 50 arrays on same index to one with PySpark map-reducer function.

Example:

```
array1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
array2 = {3,4,2,3,5,6,7}
....
```

the result should be `array3 = {4,6,5,7,10,12,14}`.

This is a project requirement to use PySpark on Map-Reducer platform.

Now I can figure out the map part:

```
NUM_SAMPLES = 50
result = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, NUM_SAMPLES)).map(random_generation)
```

The result here contains 50 arrays. Function `random_generation` gives one array with 7 random numbers.

Please anyone can provide me the suggestion on the reduce part.

Comment: `array1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` etc. are not arrays, they are [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) and therefore contain only distinct values (distinct by hash).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think it's easier to use DataFrame.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()

arrays = [
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    [3,4,2,3,5,6,7],
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(arrays)
s = df.groupBy().sum().collect()

print s
print list(s[0])
```

**Result**

```
[Row(sum(_1)=5, sum(_2)=8, sum(_3)=8, sum(_4)=11, sum(_5)=15, sum(_6)=18, sum(_7)=21)]
[5, 8, 8, 11, 15, 18, 21]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is not actually adding two arrays. We have 50 similar arrays to sum up. It seems that the method you provide can only solve the two array adding but no more than two. How are we going to deal with the problem with 50 array sum up?

Thank you very much!!!